# Promise and node making variables available in different functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have three functions, I wish to make the variable from function one and two available in function three.

**Function one**

Bellow in function one I am trying to include that variable `emailUser` in resolve to use it in a third function.

```
var firstMethod = function() {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(function() {
            app.post('/api/data', function (req, res) {
                console.log(req.body);
                var emailUser = req.body.email;
                res.send(emailUser);
            });
            console.log('first method completed');
            resolve({data: emailUser });
        }, 2000);
    });
    return promise;
};
```

**Second function**

This function I am trying to pass `api_key` for use in the third function.

```
var secondMethod = function(someStuff) {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(function() {
            nodePardot.PardotAPI({
                userKey: 34535345,
                email: fsf@dd.com,
                password: fd3sv34f,
                DEBUG: true
            }, function (err, client) {
                if (err) {
                    // Authentication failed
                    console.error("Authentication Failed", err)
                } else {
                    // Authentication successful
                    var api_key = client.apiKey;
                    console.log("Authentication successful !", api_key);
                }
            });
            console.log('second method completed');
            resolve({newData: api_key});
        }, 2000);
    });
    return promise;
};
```

**Third function**

This function I would like to access the variables from function one and two. I have included a console log so that I may see the variables printed on my console.

I would also like to access these functions for use in this third function/ method.

```
  var thirdMethod= function() {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
 console.log('show both functions', emailUser, api_key);
        }, 3000);
    });
    return promise;
};
    
    firstMethod()
        .then(secondMethod)
        .then(thirdMethod);
```

Comment: `access the variables` which variables? Note: you can only "access" the resolved value from a promise - also, your third method never resolves, so why does it need to be a promise?

Comment: the var i need is emailUser  and api_key. i also need promise for function order so that certain function run before the other

Comment: sure, but thirdMethod does not need to me a promise, there's nothing asynchronous about it - forget that, didn't see the setTimeout because it's not there

Comment: good point, tbh its a striped out function to cut down the copy and past, but i understand your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to resolve inside the function body when the API call has get response.

```
var firstMethod = function() {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(function() {
            app.post('/api/data', function (req, res) {
                console.log(req.body);
                var emailUser = req.body.email;                            
                res.send(emailUser);

                //resolve when get the response
                resolve({data: emailUser });
            });

        }, 2000);
    });
    return promise;
};
```

---

You must need to resolve or reject when error. Here I resolve the error and set `api_key` as `empty`.

```
var secondMethod = function(someStuff) {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(function() {
            nodePardot.PardotAPI({
                userKey: 34535345,
                email: fsf@dd.com,
                password: fd3sv34f,
                DEBUG: true
            }, function (err, client) {
                if (err) {
                    // Authentication failed
                    console.error("Authentication Failed", err);
                    resolve({newData: ''});

                } else {
                    // Authentication successful
                    var api_key = client.apiKey;

                    console.log("Authentication successful !", api_key);
                    resolve({newData: api_key});
                }
            });

        }, 2000);
    });
    return promise;
};
```

---

```
function thirdMethod(result) {
  console.log('show both functions', result[0].data, result[1].newData);
};

Promise.all([firstMethod(), secondMethod()])
.then(thirdMethod);
```

---

**For Reference**

```
var firstMethod = function() {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {

            //resolve when get the response
            resolve({
                data: "a"
            });
        });

    }, 2000);

    return promise;
};

var secondMethod = function() {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {

            //resolve when get the response
            resolve({
                data: "b"
            });
        });

    }, 2000);

    return promise;
};

var thirdMethod = function(result) {
    console.log(result[0].data, result[1].data);
};

Promise.all([firstMethod(), secondMethod()]).then(thirdMethod);
```

**Output:** 
`a`  `b`

Comment: your thirdMethod expects an array, but secondMethod resolves an object

Comment: Hmm ive tried this but third function dose not seem to print out the results in the console

Comment: @Beep you get any error? it perfectly running on my local.

Comment: this will run first and second in "parallel" - is that a requirement now? not according to the question

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX, I did not see that. if I add then.second would that solve ?

Comment: nothing wrong with the first two running in parallel, they don't rely on each other, I was just pointing that out in case they do so "in real code"

Answer (score 0):

your first promise resolves

```
{data: emailUser }
```

therefore `somestuff` in the second promise would be that

in your second method, you could resolve

```
{data: somestuff.data, newData: api_key}
```

then the third method can be written

```
var thirdMethod= function(values) {
```

and it would have the data from the first two promises

Overall, your code can be written (ES2016+)

```
var firstMethod = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => app.post('/api/data', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    var emailUser = req.body.email;
    res.send(emailUser);
    resolve({ emailUser });
}), 2000));

var secondMethod = ({ emailUser }) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => nodePardot.PardotAPI({
    userKey: 34535345,
    email: 'fsf@dd.com',
    password: 'fd3sv34f',
    DEBUG: true
}, (err, client) => {
    if (err) {
        // Authentication failed
        console.error("Authentication Failed", err);
        reject(err);
    } else {
        // Authentication successful
        var api_key = client.apiKey;
        console.log("Authentication successful !", api_key);
        resolve({ emailUser, api_key });
    }
}), 2000));

var thirdMethod = ({ emailUser, api_key }) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('show both functions', emailUser, api_key);
    resolve('done');
}, 3000));

firstMethod().then(secondMethod).then(thirdMethod);
```

Comment: Hmm ill need to look into ES2016+ as my current stack is node and angular

Answer (score 0):

First you need to fix `firstMethod` and `secondMethod`. In `firstMethod` the `emailUser` variable is only set inside the callback function, it does not exist where you try to use it to resolve the promise. You need to move the promise resolution inside the callback.

Likewise in `secondMethod` the variable `api_key` only exists in the callback, and then only if the function succeeded. You need to put calls to `resolve()` and `reject()` inside that callback and remove the `resolve()` outside.

Once you have done that you should be resolving both promises with the correct values and your code can be:

```
function thirdMethod([emailUSer, api_key]) {
  console.log('show both functions', emailUser, api_key);
};

Promise.all([firstMethod(), secondMethod()])
.then(thirdMethod);
```

Note that as `thirdMethod` is only called by `then()` you don't need to create a `Promise` unless you have something asynchronous to do: anything it returns will be automatically wrapped in a `Promise` for you.

Comment: Ok looks good, but im very new to promise and still learning ill try and implement this in my code and see if i can get it working. thanks